# MVC3 - Getting the actual page path rather than Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a route as

```
http://www.domain.com/Test/12345678
```

This points to

```
http://www.domian.com/SomeArea/SomeController/SomeAction?customerId=12345678
```

- Request.RawUrl gives the path as http://www.domain.com/Test/12345678
- Request.Url.AbsolutePath gives the path as /Test/12345678
- Request.Url.LocalPath gives the path as /Test/12345678
- Request.Url.AbsoluteUri gives the path as http://www.domain.com/Test/12345678

So, how do i get the actual page path that is currently displaying as:

```
/SomeArea/SomeController/SomeAction
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `Url.RouteUrl`

Comment: Request.Path gives /Test/12345678

Comment: I have haven't been able to complete Url.RouteUrl. I played with passing the parameters to it but then got side tracked with a different request. At this point i am not sure what to pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Request.FilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filepath.aspx) is what you are looking for.

If you want the [PathInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx) trailer you can use [Request.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path.aspx)